# Prove that $g$ is integrable and $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$ if $f$ is integrable and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all but finitely many $x\in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I've started by assuming $g(x_0)\neq f(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in [a,b]$. I let $\delta>0$ then

$$\int_a^b f=\int_a^{x_0-\delta}f+\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f+\int_{x_0+\delta}^b f$$

$$=\int_a^{x_0-\delta}g+\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f+\int_{x_0+\delta}^b g$$ since $g=f \ \forall x\neq x_0$.

But now I'm a little stuck, any hints or other ideas appreciated!

Comment: Note that $|\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f| \leq 2M\delta$ where $M$ is any upper bound of $|f|$ on $[a,b].$ You may also note that it is sufficient to consider the case when $f$ and $g$ differ at one point.

Comment: The question is not even intelligible. It reads as if words have been randomly permuted. Please restate it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $h = f - g$ and note that $h$ is integrable and zero at all but finitely many points. So your problem reduces to proving that
$$\int_a^bf = 0$$
if $f$ is zero at all but finitely many points.